# ResourceTaskStart indipendent

Tags: anylogic

Is it possible to use the ResourceTaskStart block independently of the main action flowchart? All the solutions with this block, that I have found, require the resource to be seized in the main flowchart. If I instead wanted to create a parallel action flowchart, within which one of my resources performs actions, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `Enter` and `Exit` blocks instead. You send your resource agents to the former at some point using `myEnterBlock.take(agent)`.

However, be careful to do this only when the resource is not seized, else it could lead to unintended problems.